# Para que se utiliza charAt(0)?

Tags: java

Tengo un código de ejemplo que dice lo siguiente:

```
(uno.getText().trim().charAt(0)+"\n"+   
dos.getText().trim().charAt(0)+"\n"+   
tres.getText().trim().charAt(0)+"\n"+   
cuatro.getText().trim().charAt(0));
```

Esto lo hicimos para que muestre en un `textarea` las iniciales de los nombres que el usuario ingreso, pero no recuerdo cómo funcionaba.

También necesitaría saber que hace el `"\n"+`, y porque se utiliza `trim()`

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas la [documentación de la clase String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), en ella tienes una sección con métodos y sus explicaciones.

Comment: Edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico. Evita preguntar varias cosas distintas a la vez. Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta.

Answer (score 5):

- charAt(indice) es una funcion de String que devuelve el caracter ubicado en la posicion indice de la cadena
- /n es el caracter especial para salto de cadena
- trim tambien es una funcion de String, pero en este caso devuelve la misma cadena despues de haber eliminado los espacios en blanco al inicio y al final de la cadena

En el codigo que publicaste primero se eliminan los espacios en blanco con trim, trim devuelve otro String asi que se le puede aplicar cualquier funcion de String nuevamente, en este caso charAt(0) devuelve la inicial, que es lo que buscas.

Finalmente, para darle formato a los resultados se concatenan separados por un salto de linea

Fuentes: [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)